# How to get directive to apply focus to its wrapped input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've built an attribute directive (`focus-on-event`) which watches for an event on the `$rootScope` and when it's triggered sets the focus onto the attached element.

The problem is when I want to add that directive to another custom directive wrapping an `input` (`wrapped-input`). I need it to go into my element and apply the focus to the input.

I tried binding to the `focus` event of `wrapped-input`, but that never seems to be triggered. I also tried broadcasting another event but that doesn't seem to work. If I can make either approach work, I can just put the focus on the wrapped input element right from `wrapped-input`'s link function.

How can I make this work?

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  
  .directive('wrappedInput', function() {
    return {
      template: '<input placeholder="wrapped input">',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on('hello', function() {
          alert('This never gets called');
        });
        element.bind('focus', function() {
          alert('This never gets called either');
        });
      }
    }
  })
  
  .directive('clickTriggers', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      scope: { clickTriggers: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast(scope.clickTriggers);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  
  .directive('focusOnEvent', function() {
    return {
      scope: { focusOnEvent: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on(scope.focusOnEvent, function(onEvent, keypressEvent) {
          element[0].focus();
          scope.$broadcast('hello');
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <wrapped-input focus-on-event="event1"></wrapped-input>
    <button click-triggers="event1">Trigger 'event1'</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" focus-on-event="event2" placeholder="native input">
    <button click-triggers="event2">Trigger 'event2'</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. broadcast from rootScope.
2. broadcast from parentScope
3. emit from directive and have parent scope controller catch and broadcast it.

Comment: I gave that a go (but with `$scope`). Still nothing :(

Comment: the scope in `focusOnEvent` doesn't seem to be the same as that in `wrappedInput`

Comment: You are broadcasting from rootScope, so any scope should get the event. Updated, try it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid broadcasting from rootScope from `focus-on-event` if I can. I'll try tinkering with `emit` tomorrow morning. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I think your directives are siblings, hence simple emit will not work. I had listed the options available.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. Unfortunately, these suffer from the issue that my `input` and `wrapped-input` both share the same scope(?). That is, clicking either button will trigger the alert on `wrapped-input`. What I really want is to have have the clients of the `focus-on-event` directive be in control of whether it gets focus itself or passes it to one of its children. I do not want focusOnEvent itself know about where it will be used...